# Laravel - message": "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"me@yahoo.com\" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel, postman

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I created an endpoint for user signup. After successful signup authentication mail will be sent to the user. I am using mailtrap to do this.

AuthController

```
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'activation_token' => str_random(60)
        ]);
        $user->save();
        $avatar = Avatar::create(strtoupper($user->name))->getImageObject()->encode('png');
        Storage::put('avatars/'.$user->id.'/avatar.png', (string) $avatar);
        $user->notify(new SignupActivate($user));
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }


    public function signupActivate($token)
    {
        $user = User::where('activation_token', $token)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'This activation token is invalid.'
            ], 404);
        }
        $user->active = true;
        $user->activation_token = '';
        $user->email_verified_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $user->save();
        return $user;
    }
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

mail.php

```
<?php

return [


    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),


    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),


        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', '**********'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', '**********'),


    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],


    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

When I posted it to the database through Postman, it suppose to send an email. It posted into database, but no mail was sent. I got this error:

[image: postman error]

Comment: Did you install `imagemagick`? if you didn't follow this link https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

Comment: That username and password looks kinda short. Have your tried ```php artisan config:cache```

Comment: @GameO7er - Yes, I installed imagick. that's why you cannot see imagick error anymore

Comment: @Dino Numić - That is not the real username and password.

Comment: @Dino Numić - It works when I applied    php artisan config:cache.       Thanks